# Where can I watch the Shuuen no Shiori (Bookmark of Demise) music videos?

Tags: bookmark-of-demise

Preferably with English Subs. The YouTube videos either don't have the audio due to copyright or don't have English Subs.  I bumped into the project randomly and wanted to listen to the songs and watch the videos but only YouTube video show up on Google.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you'll find a version with English subs (there aren't any "official" subs, at minimum), but you can find the ones that have music videos on 150P's Niconico account.

- [Kodoku no Kakurenbo](http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm17804161) ([alternate](http://www.mmcafe.com/nico.html#http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm17804161))
- [Nisemono Chuuihou](http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm18060733) ([alternate](http://www.mmcafe.com/nico.html#http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm18060733))
- [Kanzen Hanzai Love Letter](http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm18172311) ([alternate](http://www.mmcafe.com/nico.html#http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm18172311))
- [Saru Mane Isutori Game](http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm19216490) ([alternate](http://www.mmcafe.com/nico.html#http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm19216490))
- [Arikitari Heroes](http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm19811204) ([alternate](http://www.mmcafe.com/nico.html#http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm19811204))
- [Makeinu Shijou Shugi](http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm20350758) ([alternate](http://www.mmcafe.com/nico.html#http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm20350758))
- [Shuuen no Shiori](http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm21552346) ([alternate](http://www.mmcafe.com/nico.html#http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm21552346))

If you don't have an account on Niconico and don't want to make one, use the alternate links instead. No guarantees that those links won't crap out at some point, though.